# angular js specify ng-model dynamically and access that text box value back

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to assign a ng-model to an input dynamically and retrieve all text box the value on button click.  alert(x.WeekNumber) is not giving value

**template**

```
<table class="table-bordered">   
    <tr ng-repeat="x in weekOneData">
        <td>{{x.dayDate}}</td>
        <td><input type="number" value="0" id="x.WeekNumber" />{{x.WeekNumber}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="TestFunction()">testing</button>
```

**controller**

```
 $scope.weekOneData = [];
for (var index = 1; index <= 7; index++) {
    var ob = new Object();
    ob.dayDate = formattedDate;
    ob.WeekNumber = index;$scope.weekOneData[index - 1] = ob;
   }
$scope.TestFunction = function () {
  //  sum=textbox1+textbox2+textbox3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you want to achieve with this code. But the problem is that you reference `x` outside of the `ng-repeat` scope. Try this:

```
<table class="table-bordered">   
    <tr ng-repeat="x in weekOneData">
        <td>{{x.dayDate}}</td>
        <td><input type="number" value="0" id="x.WeekNumber" />{{x.WeekNumber}}
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="TestFunction(x)">testing</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a 'working' example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/aiWasYUnV19d7JMPnjJZ?p=preview

Comment: Hi Mark  my button is outside the ng-repeat  i want to get all textbox value (user entered values) on button click